# cURL -- cookies and sessions

Tags: php, curl

I would like to understand the four options of cURL for cookies:

```
CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION  
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR
CURLOPT_COOKIE
```

I understand that `COOKIEJAR` is meant for writing cookies, and `COOKIEFILE` is meant for reading. 
So what is `COOKIESESSION` for ? 
The `CURLOPT_COOKIE` is custom, but can I use it to maintain a session with the server ?

Comment: isnt second and fourth same ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To understand `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION`, you need to know a couple of things about cookies.  Cookies have expiration dates that are set by the website that issues the cookie.  If an expiration date of a cookie has passed, the browser/client will not send it, and it will be deleted by the client.  If a cookie is set with NO expiration date, the browser should use that cookie until the browser session is closed, or the user logs out and the cookie gets unset.

That said, `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` is a way to get cURL to simulate having closed the browser.  If the `COOKIEFILE` has some session cookies in it (cookies with no expiration), it will normally send these if they were present in the file.  If you set `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION`, then it will NOT send any of the cookies that have no expiration date.

`CURLOPT_COOKIE` just gives you a means of setting the cookie data that will be sent to the server in raw format.  This is useful if for example you have a raw HTTP cookie that you would like to send.  Without this option, you would have to get those cookies into the `COOKIEFILE`, or set a custom HTTP header `Cookie:` with the raw value you had.

Comment: I need to use two seperate scripts that need to share the same session cookie. so I would like to **(1)** start a new session with the server, **(2)** maintain the session for several pages (init,set,exec,close), **(3)** close the script. **(4)** open the new script, **(5)** resume the same session, **(6)** and close and delete the cookie. So I should start with COOKIESESSION=TRUE, COOKIEJAR=cookiefilename and COOKIEFILE=cookiefilename, for the first. COOKIESESSION=FALSE, COOKIEFILE=cookiefilename for script 1, and simply go on in script 2 without the COOOKIESESSION=TRUE ?

Comment: It depends on whether or not the login cookies are actually session cookies or persistent cookies.  If it is the latter, than COOKIESESSION will not help.  To be safe, you could just clear the contents of the cookie file before you start in script 1.  Alternatively you could have script 2 actually logout of the site in question by hitting the logout url.  I think in both script 1 and script 2, I would specify both COOKIEFILE and COOKIEJAR, so that if when script2 makes a request, any modifications to the cookie will be saved to the file.  COOKIESESSION is false by default as well.

Comment: they are sequential. after script 2 finishes I delete the cookiefile using unlink. I guess I can tell it is a session cookie by this: PHPSESSID. So it is. Does what I said one comment before, (COOKIESESSION=TRUE for the first, false for the rest)  hold true?

Comment: Since you're deleting the cookie file when done, script 1 creates a new curl session specifying only COOKIEFILE and COOKIEJAR.  script 1 logs in, does what it needs to and calls curl_close.  Script two runs and specifies COOKIEFILE and COOKIEJAR as options, does what it needs to do and then deletes the file.  Those basic steps should be all that is necessary.  No need to mess with COOKIESESSION at all.